# The shortcut icons of IE and User folder on the left taskbar are gone, how can I bring them back

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

There used to be some shortcut icons of IE, User Folder on the left taskbar in my Windows 7, but there are gone now.

I want them back but I don't know how to do it.

What shall I do now?

Like this one I found on Google:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### I want them back but I don't know how to do it.

1. Run Internet Explorer.
2. Right click the icon and select "Pin this program to taskbar"

   > [image]

Repeat for Explorer.

Note: You can also drag and drop items to the taskbar to pin them.

---

#### Further Reading

- [How to Permanently Pin a Program to the Windows 7 Taskbar](http://www.wikihow.com/Permanently-Pin-a-Program-to-the-Windows-7-Taskbar)